# Dynamic and static linking and deployment in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, deployment, static-linking

I've an unmanaged C++ project in Visual Studio 2010. It uses boost, glut and another library from a vendor.

I've set up the project to create a more "dll-indepenendent" executable possible. All the boost libraries are linked statically and there is no need of dll in the directory where the executable stays.

Same thing for the Glut, I've linked the static glut32.lib instead of the glut32.dll and again no problem.

I've selected for the Runtime libraries the NON-dll version, i.e. Multithreaded Debug (for Debug configuration) and Multithreaded for Release configuration.

Now, the vendor I was speaking before, provides two alternatives a Vendor.lib and a Vendor.dll.

The Vendor.lib is added in the Linker->Additional dependencies but at runtime I always have to put the Vendor.dll in the same directory of the executable, otherwise the runtime environment complains because it doesn't find the Vendor.dll library.

How should I solve this issue? I would like to avoid to put in every directory the .dll file.

I don't want to put the dll in the same directory of the exe and in general what are the guidelines to deploy unmanaged c++ console applications in Visual Studio?

I know there are many questions and pages about this argument but none of those clarified me this point.

Some idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Microsoft is a bit funny in the way it handles this: when you create a
.dll, you also create a .lib, which contains the public symbols in the
.dll.  You must link against the .lib in order to load the .dll at
runtime, but this .lib is still not a static library.  If your vendor
provides a version for static linking, there will either be no .dll, or
two .lib (presumably in different directories or with different names).
Just another example of Microsoft making serious development more
difficult than necessary.

Comment: This isn't MS specific. Linux has import libraries too.

Comment: Unix has two types of "libraries": libraries (.a files) and shared objects (.so files).  A vendor providing a library (in the general sense) will normally provide both.  If you link against the .a file, you link statically, and if you link against the .so, you link dynamically.  The problem with the Microsoft solution is that 1) you have two distinct files for dynamic linking, and 2) one of the files has the same name as a static library would.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Probably I'm not the only one getting confused on this topic. So, as you are saying, there are two kind of .lib files, one created when a dynamic library is needed and another that can be a static library. I don't find another Vendor.lib file, so I guess I'm in the first case...Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

The Vendor.lib needs to be a statically-compiled library.  If when you link this you still need Vendor.dll, it sounds like Vendor.lib is actually an import library rather than a static library.

Check to see if the vendor provides another Vendor.lib (which should be a good bit larger than your current .lib) which is a static library and try linking to that.  If so, you won't need the dll.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have other .lib files in that library, so I guess that I'm in the dynamic link case.
There are no other methods to include the .dll rather than copying it in the executable directory (or copying them into System32 folder?)

Comment: If you have access to the vendor source, you could compile the vendor.lib yourself as a static library.  Otherwise, if you have to use the shared lib, then your exe needs access to this at runtime, which means adding it to the folder with the exe, or putting it in a folder which is included in %PATH% (the convention being the System32 folder).